# i want to count record from the table by foreign key

Tags: php

This is the shopping cart dropdown. I have made for my e-commerce store. Now I want if both the products in the `cart` Table have the same `category Id` in the table then I want to show a single product with a quantity of two. `for example (2 * $240) .`

[image]

this is the database table picture.

[image]

And this is the code for showing the products in the dropdown.

```
    <ul class="header-cart-wrapitem">
       <?php
          $displayCart = "SELECT cart.*,products.product_img1 FROM `cart` 
            join products on products.product_id = cart.product_id 
            WHERE cart.status = 'enabled' order by cart.cart_id DESC";
            $resultCart = mysqli_query($conn,$displayCart);
            while($rowCart = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCart)){?>
       <li class="header-cart-item">
          <div class="header-cart-item-img">
             <img src="<?=$base_url .'pages/Ajax/'.$rowCart['product_img1'];?>" alt="IMG">
          </div>
          <div class="header-cart-item-txt">
             <a href="#" class="header-cart-item-name">
             <?=$rowCart['product_name'];?>
             </a>
             <span class="header-cart-item-info">
             <?=$rowCart['product_qty'];?> x $<?=$rowCart['product_price'];?>
             </span>
          </div>
       </li>
       <?php } ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Just add group by product_id in your query which will only return distinct value of products which you can use further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick!

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(product_id) as count,
  cart.*,
  products.product_img1
FROM 
  `cart` 
  join products on products.product_id = cart.product_id 
WHERE 
  cart.status = 'enabled' 
GROUP BY 
  product_id 
order by 
  cart.cart_id DESC
```

Hope this helps!